# Cannot read property 'push' of null in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i get flat list from server and i must create a tree that list .

this is my model :

```
export interface ClaimManagerList {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  parentId: number;
  isChilde: boolean;
  childs: Childes[];
}

export interface Childes {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  parentId: number;
  isChilde: boolean;
}
```

and in this code i convert flat list to tree list -> childs add to this property `childs`  :

```
  return this.claimsManagerService.getAll(this.searchParam).pipe(
  map(data => {
    data['records'].forEach(element => {
      let model = {} as ClaimManagerList;
      if (element.parentId == null) {
        model.id = element.id;
        model.isChilde = element.isChilde;
        model.parentId = element.parentId;
        model.title = element.title;
        data['records'].forEach(child => {
          if (child.parentId == element.id) {
            let childe = {} as Childes;
            childe.id = child.id;
            childe.isChilde = child.isChilde;
            childe.parentId = child.parentId;
            childe.title = child.title;
            model.childs.push(childe)
          }
        })
        this.claims.push(model)
      }
    })
    return this.claims;
  })
```

but it show me error in this line :

`model.childs.push(childe)`

> Cannot read property 'push'

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening as `model.childs` is not set to an empty array at the beginning. We can resolve this like:

```
if(!model.childs) model.childs = [] as Childes[];
model.childs.push(childe)  // This line should work fine now.
```

Comment: thanks . can i you show me best practice for this convert ????

Comment: It's quite simple, we are just setting empty array here with the type of array of `Childes` interface. This has to be done here as in the interface we can not set the default values. Also, you can checkout [Typescript - Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to propose some changes to your code to order to improve this. I hope these changes will be useful for you.

```
return this.claimsManagerService.getAll(this.searchParam).pipe(
  map((data: any) => {
    data.records.forEach((element: any) => {
      let model: ClaimManagerList = {};
      if (element.parentId == null) {
        model.id = element.id;
        model.isChilde = element.isChilde;
        model.parentId = element.parentId;
        model.title = element.title;
        model.childs = [];
        data.records.forEach((child: any) => {
          if (child.parentId == element.id) {
            let childe = {} as Childes;
            childe.id = child.id;
            childe.isChilde = child.isChilde;
            childe.parentId = child.parentId;
            childe.title = child.title;
            model.childs.push(childe)
          }
        })
        this.claims.push(model)
      }
    })
    return this.claims;
  })
```